# Populate a listview with threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm developing a "chat" app that retrieves some data (the messages) from a database (firebase real-time database), does some manipulations and then populates a listview in order to display them on the screen. I have 2 types of messages: 
The first type is text messages, the manipulations on them are very short and don't take a long.
The second type is pictures. The manipulations on them are longer than on text (few seconds).

When the activity starts, the app retrieves all the messages from the database, and has to do the manipulations on each one of them (text and pictures). Before we see anything on the screen, it has to finish the manipulations on all the messages and then it takes a lot of time.

My question is: is there a way to populate each item in a different thread? Like to see on the screen the text messages appear (because the manipulations on them are fast) and then the pictures when each one of them finish at its own time (same idea like a website when we see the text before all the pictures finish to be loaded). Of course the messages need to appear in the same order like they were in the database (actually I retrieve them with the onChildAdded() function).

I really hope it was clear, and if not I will be happy to clarify any point.

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

Define them as different Threads:

```
[...]recive messages

if (/*message an image?*/) {
  new Thread(() -> {
    //Do something
  }).start();
} else {
  new Thread(() -> {
    //Do something else
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: This solution won't keep the original order of the messages as they appear in the DB. If the text messages finish before the pictures, so an item on the listview will be created and the order will change

Comment: Why don't order them before? I don't know how your program is organized but this shouldn't be that hard. Add them in a Queue or just save the time the message was posted.

Comment: You can also just use a placeholder image (what most chatapps do) and replace it once the image is ready.

Comment: Order them seem in a container seems to be a good solution. I will try that. Thank you for your answers!